# dist-upgrade: EFI directory not found error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, upgrade, dpkg

My updates in Ubuntu LTS 16.04 stopped working, possibly after a Windows 10 update.

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
Luetaan pakettiluetteloita... Valmis
Muodostetaan riippuvuussuhteiden puu       
Luetaan tilatiedot... Valmis        
Käsitellään päivitystä... Valmis
0 päivitetty, 0 uutta asennusta, 0 poistettavaa ja 0 päivittämätöntä.
2 ei asennettu kokonaan tai poistettiin.
Toiminnon jälkeen käytetään 0  t lisää levytilaa.
Haluatko jatkaa? [K/e] k
Tehdään asetuksia: grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.66.16+2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: virhe: cannot find EFI directory.
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
aliprosessi komentotiedosto post-installation asennettu palautti virhetilakoodin 1
Tehdään asetuksia: shim-signed (1.33.1~16.04.1+13-0ubuntu2) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: virhe: cannot find EFI directory.
dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
aliprosessi komentotiedosto post-installation asennettu palautti virhetilakoodin 1
Käsittelyssä tapahtui liian monta virhettä:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

My hard drive configuration is as follows:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: [XXXX]

Laite           Start      Loppu   Sektorit  Size Tyyppi
/dev/sda1        2048    1333247    1331200  650M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     1333248    1865727     532480  260M EFI System
/dev/sda3     1865728    2127871     262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4     2127872 1113586243 1111458372  530G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  1113587712 1115541503    1953792  954M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6  1115541504 1167970303   52428800   25G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda7  1167970304 1184747519   16777216    8G Linux-sivutus
/dev/sda8  1184747520 1453182975  268435456  128G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda9  1920847872 1953513471   32665600 15,6G Microsoft basic data[/CODE]
```

Note that the grub works just fine in boot and Ubuntu starts normally. It is only the updates that do not work anymore.

I'm stuck and would hate to re-install - help needed!

Answer (score 2):

I got some very good help on other forums and used the BootInfo tools to get more information about the grub and boot

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

From the BootInfo report it turned out that /boot/efi was commented out in the file /sda6/etc/fstab:

```
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
# UUID=EE10-4B61 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
```

The problem was solved by commenting out the UUID ... /boot/efi row in fstab.

Fore more info please see https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2384690